# Countdown not resetting as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have created a countdown which is counting down to a specific time (hh:mm:ss) on a daily base, lets say 7pm or 19:00:00. Once 7pm is passed, the countdown should reset to 23:59:59, but in stead it is counting up the time (-00 -00 -01) it has elapsed from the previous time set.

How can I make the timer so that it resets to the next 24h once it has passed?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/p3f2X/ (try to set the time to a past time of your day - eg 4pm in your timezone, then set it to 3pm to see the error)

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
      timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Comment: You simply want to calculate the number of seconds to the count-down time, modulus it with the number of seconds in a day, then do a similar thing for the hours and minutes remaining. Using `Date` to get the parts just confuses the matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the real problem is here is that you don't want to go have a negative hours, minutes, or seconds variable, to solve this you can do this:

Using this code you can also change the numbers to 19, 0, and 0 as that's clearer, and prevents displaying `60 seconds`.

```
var hours=19-now.getHours()-1;
if(hours<0)hours+=24;
var minutes=0-now.getMinutes()-1;
if(minutes<0)minutes+=60;
var seconds=0-now.getSeconds();
if(seconds<0)seconds+=60;
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3f2X/7/)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the question is about a maximum of one day.

Comment: Indeed, it should refresh daily to the next 24 hours once passed. (there is a link who will change daily depending on what 24 hours it is in).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie this will work for multiple days, as soon as it's 19 o'clock the clock will start ticking from 24:00

Comment: I will withdraw my comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs;    
  var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();
    if(now.getHours()>18)
        hrs=24+18-now.getHours();
        else
        hrs= 18-now.getHours();
      timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);  
    console.log(now.getHours());
}
setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```